# Version Helper functions for Windows XP

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

In my application I need to check windows version. I'm using [Version Helper functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx) in `Visual Studio 2013 (v120) platform toolset`. But then the program does not work in Windows XP. error is:

```
'xxx.exe' is not a valid win32 application
```

So I changed platform toolset to `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)`. But in this case application will not compile.
The error is:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'VersionHelpers.h': No such file or directory
```

What can I do? Can I use old [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) function? MSDN says:

```
GetVersionEx may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the Version Helper APIs
```

But may be I should use it for now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've managed to solve it using Remmy Lebeau's comment.

I copied `VersionHelpers.h` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um` and `winapifamily.h` and `sdkddkver.h` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared` into my project and changed some includes in them.

Now it compiles with Windows XP toolset.

I've tested it and it's working as expected in all versions of windows.

Comment: can you detail what you changed in the "includes"

Comment: @physicist I don't remember what I did. But it was straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: try to link the functions manually with GetProcAddress to see what is available, If the new API is not, then the old must be, so you can use the one you managed to link without errors.

I am assuming you are building 32bit or 64bit and the OS in both cases is compatible.

EDIT:

GetVersionEx(), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is exported from kerner32.dll in XP, so you can try to link it using

GetProcAddress() [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also has a suggestion by Microsft using "GetNativeSystemInfo".

The new API function

```
IsWindowsXPOrGreater()   // also exported from kernel32.dll and ntdll.dll
```

can also be linked the same way using GetProcAddress(). This function will return an error if the function you are trying to link is not found, so you will know which one you have available. Then you call the available one and get the version info you need.

You only need to define the function prototypes yourself instead of using the headers, then define two function pointers, one for each, then assign them a NULL value initially until you try to link the functions. Then one pointer (or both) will end up with a value, and you can use the latest one available to call the linked API.

Comment: So Version Helper API can't be used in Windows XP right? then why it has the function `IsWindowsXPOrGreater`? and also can u elaborate more on your answer. I didn't quiet get what should I do.

Comment: `IsWindowsXPOrGreater()` and the other Version Helper functions are not exported from any DLL, so you cannot use `GetProcAddress()` to access them dynamically. They are inline functions that wrap `VerifyVersionInfo()` and `VerSetConditionMask()` instead. And those functions have been available since Windows 2000, so there is no need to use `GetProcAddress()` to access them, either (unless you need to support Win9x/ME/NT4). The easiest solution would be to make a copy of `VersionHelpers.h` where the XP toolset can find it.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs Here you'll find an example code of what you have to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx included the call via a function pointer.